# Using the angular and ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, internationalization

I do localization application.
I'am using on this tutorial:  http://robferguson.org/2015/07/22/internationalisation-i18n-and-localisation-l10n-for-ionic-apps/
Triggered by `ionic serve` in the browser console gives the following error:

> lib.js:26793 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider:
>   translateFilterProvider <- translateFilter
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/$injector/unpr?p0=translateFilterProvider%20%3C-%20translateFilter
>       at http://192.168.1.66:8100/js/lib.js:13438:12
>       at http://192.168.1.66:8100/js/lib.js:17787:19
>       at Object.getService [as get] (http://192.168.1.66:8100/js/lib.js:17940:39)
>       at http://192.168.1.66:8100/js/lib.js:17792:45
>       at Object.getService [as get] (http://192.168.1.66:8100/js/lib.js:17940:39)
>       at http://192.168.1.66:8100/js/lib.js:32696:24
>       at isStateless (http://192.168.1.66:8100/js/lib.js:27441:12)
>       at findConstantAndWatchExpressions (http://192.168.1.66:8100/js/lib.js:27498:33)
>       at http://192.168.1.66:8100/js/lib.js:27452:7
>       at forEach (http://192.168.1.66:8100/js/lib.js:13691:20)

What I am doing wrong?
Here is my project: https://github.com/igorlimansky/esteem/tree/develop
If you can not help it advise to read on this subject.

Comment: Refer my ans :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47317089/multiple-languages-for-your-app

Answer (score 0):

I think you just forgot to inject angular translate module in your module maybe try to replace this:

```
    var app = angular.module('steem', [
        'ionic', 
        'ngStorage', 
        'ngCordova',
        'wiz.markdown',
        'rzModule',
        'ion-floating-menu',
        'ja.qr'
        //'ionic.contrib.ui.ionThread'
    ]);
```

by this:

```
var app = angular.module('steem', [
    'ionic', 
    'ngStorage', 
    'ngCordova',
    'wiz.markdown',
    'rzModule',
    'ion-floating-menu',
    'ja.qr',
    'pascalprecht.translate'
    //'ionic.contrib.ui.ionThread'
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check these two points you have done correctly:-
 Include all the translate js and inject the module

```
// Including js correctly
<script src="bower_components/angular-translate/angular-translate.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-translate-loader-static-files/angular-translate-loader-static-files.js"></script>

 //Inject modules
 angular.module('vardyger', [
   'ionic',                 
   'pascalprecht.translate'  // inject the angular-translate module
 ])
```