# Multiple Languages for your app?

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using the ionic framework with Ionic Creator.

Is it possible to have all my text referenced to any String file. And this file can be different for each language so that i can change my displayed language dynamically?

Thanks

Comment: Yes you can, if you are using angularjs I suggest this awesome [module](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate)

Comment: Ionic >= 2? Then http://www.ngx-translate.com is the way to go

Comment: Thanks I will try the module. At moment it seems ionic creator works with on lonic 1

Answer (score 0):

This is my working Example clone from github.
[Github Repo](https://github.com/husainsr/Internationalize-Ionic)